# Errors only when testing app on real iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I seem to be having an issue getting any of my apps to run on a real Iphone. I have just started out and I have 3 apps that work perfectly fine in the simulator. When I build to my Iphone however, it throws a fit. The error is the same for all 3 apps so I assume I am doing something wrong. All 3 show up on the phone, but they immediately back put when clicked on. I will post the highlighted line and the error message!  I hope someone can help me out because I am really excited about releasing some games!  I can't understand why it would only give me issues when testing it on a real Iphone.  Thanks for the help!
- Coleman

*this is the error*

> class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { Thread 1:
>   signal SIGABRT

*then in the window displayed*

> 2015-11-02 23:37:16.873 Dupal Danger[328:60b] +[Dupal_Danger.GameScene
>   nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0xbccf8
>   2015-11-02 23:37:16.880 Dupal Danger[328:60b] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+[Dupal_Danger.GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to class 0xbccf8'

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: `nodeWithFileNamed:` is only available in iOS 8.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you running on your phone? `nodeWithFileNamed:` is only available in [iOS 8 and above](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKNode/nodeWithFileNamed:).